# In Jupyter notebook notebook, going into editing mode immediately when assigning Markdown or headings types to cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to configure my Jupyter notebook (Firefox, OSX, although this should not matter) to behave as follows:

When a cell is assigned Markdown or headings class, it should switch to editing mode immediately. In the case of headings, the cursor should be positioned **after** the hashmarks.

The cells should render automatically on loss of focus (blur).

The overall idea is to make the notebook behave in a "less modal" way; less like vi, and more like Emacs and the Mathematica notebooks.

Presumably this can be done via adding keybinding code to custom.js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(assuming the default profile and a Unix-like system), the following code goes into ~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () { 

/* this is a utility function */
function set_editable_heading(event, level){
    event.notebook.command_mode();
    event.notebook.to_heading(undefined, level);
    event.notebook.edit_mode();

    var cm = event.notebook.get_selected_cell().code_mirror;
    cm.setCursor({line:0, ch: level+1 });
    cm.on("blur", function(){ 
        event.notebook.get_selected_cell().render(); 
    });
    return false;
}

/* ... and analogously for other heading levels and for the command mode 
   (... command_shortcuts.add_shortcut() )
 */
IPython.keyboard_manager.edit_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-1', {
    help: 'Set cell to Heading 1, editable',
    handler: function (event) {
        set_editable_heading(event, 1);
        return false;
    }
});

IPython.keyboard_manager.edit_shortcuts.add_shortcut('ctrl-m', {
    help: 'Set cell to markdown, editable',
    handler: function (event) {
        event.notebook.command_mode();
        event.notebook.to_markdown();

        event.notebook.get_selected_cell().code_mirror.on("blur", function(){ 
            event.notebook.get_selected_cell().render(); 
        });

        event.notebook.edit_mode();
        return false;
    }
});

return true; 
});
```